# How to get values from input form, and use it in one of my javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code looks like, I would like to be able to use whatever user inputs as the value for my showColor function. I used document.getElementsByName, but I got some errors Type error. Can somebody help? Thanks!

```
<input type="text" name="color" value="Input Your Fav Color">
<button type="button" onClick="showColor('red')">Show Color</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you're doing this

```
document.getElementsByName('color').value
```

You should be doing this instead

```
document.getElementsByName('test')[0].value
```

Because `getElementsByName` returns a collection, or alternatively give the element an `id` and use `getElementById` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to assign an id to the target `input` so that you can easily retrieve its value via javascript.

```
<input id="userColor" type="text" name="color" value="Input Your Fav Color" >
```

You can then retrieve the value like so:

```
var usercolor = document.getElementById('userColor').value;
```

Or using your example

```
<button type="button" onClick="showColor(document.getElementById('userColor').value)">Show Color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM:

```
<button type="button" onClick="showColor(document.getElementsByName('color')[0].value)">Show Color</button>
```

There will be problem if you have more elements with name `color` on the page, but I assume you haven't.

Comment: So you meant that getElementsByName would return an array of values of the same name?@Lolo

Comment: It's actually `NodeList`, but yes, it's collection.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to be using .getElementById("color") and have the input be

```
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="Input Your Fav Color">
```